# Canon CanoScan LiDE 20 drivers for Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, drivers, virtual-machine, scanner, canon-lide

Trying to set this scanner up on Windows 7 on my machine. 
The options are:

Purchase VueScan (Not interested in using VueScan to resolve this issue)

Try using a Virtual Machine with XP and connecting to the scanner.

I have tried using VirtualBox VM with XP guest host to set this up, however I just found out that VirutalBox does not support USB3 ports. Perhaps VMWare player will work...

Okay so this is a legacy scanner, probably easier to replace than support.

Comment: So no drivers suggested by Win7 at all? Does the scanner show up in Paint? Tried installing the XP drivers in compatibility mode? *Sometimes* that works.

Comment: Have you tried to use the Windows 7 [TWAIN drivers](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/scanners/canoscan_series/canoscan_lide_20#DriversAndSoftware) available at the Cannon site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the scanner working on my Windows 7 x64 using VMWare, VMWare support for usb is better than VirtualBox at the moment, ie supports USB3 and allows overriding USB3 to USB2. Only minor issue is that in order to use the scanner, I have to re-connect the USB port for the VM to recognise the device is connected.

PS: Thank you @CharlieRB and @Karan, for looking into this.